# Docker in Automation testing

Tags: docker, ui-automation

Can we launch browsers inside containers created with Windows 10 base image?

Currently we use one VM to run one script , which is not a good way of utilising resources.
With container technology is it possible to run multiple IE browser instances in the same VM parallel and independent to each other.

My requirement is a container with one testing tool and a IE browser to run automated test.
Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docker-Browser-Box](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-browser-box)

1. Pull the container

`docker pull sameersbn/browser-box:1.0.1-3`

1. Install the wrapper when image locally available.

   `docker run -it --rm \
   --volume /usr/local/bin:/target \
   --env BROWSER_BOX_REPO=sameersbn \
   sameersbn/browser-box:1.0.1-3 install`
2. This will install wrapper scripts to launch:

   `chromium-browser
   firefox
   google-chrome, google-chrome-stable
   tor-browser`
3. Then you can just `google-chrome {LINK}`

Reference: [Docker Browser Box README](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-browser-box/blob/master/README.md)